# Firebase Retrieving Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve specific data from just the currently logged in user. My data in my database looks like this:

[image]

For example, I want to just grab the full_name and save it in a variable userName. Below is what I'm using to grab my data

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("full_name").queryEqualToValue("userIdentifier").observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)
            // let userName = snapshot.value["full_name"] as! String
        })
```

Unfortunately, this is what my console prints.

[image]

I would appreciate any help :) Thank you!

Comment: hey tim. Are you doing authentication? what are you using for?

Comment: im trying to save the data to a local variable so i can use it to display things :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It gives you that warning message `indexOn` because you are doing a query.

> you should define the keys you will be indexing on via the .indexOn
>   rule in your Security and Firebase Rules. While you are allowed to
>   create these queries ad-hoc on the client, you will see greatly
>   improved performance when using .indexOn

As you know the name you are looking for you can directly go to that node, without a query.

```
    let ref:FIRDatabaseReference! // your ref ie. root.child("users").child("stephenwarren001@yahoo.com")

    // only need to fetch once so use single event

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if !snapshot.exists() { return }

        //print(snapshot)

        if let userName = snapshot.value["full_name"] as? String {
            print(userName)
        }
        if let email = snapshot.value["email"] as? String {
            print(email)
        }

        // can also use
        // snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("full_name").value as! String
    })
```

Comment: xcode suggested to me to add a "!" after value which I'm not sure is what we should be doing... in fact that might be what is causing it to crash(?)

Comment: its a force unwrap of an optional - if that value does not exist it will crash.

Comment: Also depending on your model design you may get back multiple snapshots. So then you would use snapshot.children and loop through them all. This tutorial is good for these basics https://www.raywenderlich.com/109706/firebase-tutorial-getting-started - the firebase starter guide is also very very good! https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: should I be force unwrapping it? I suspect that I shouldn't be since everyone has been writing it without the "!". Xcode won't build unless i force unwrap value

Comment: I'd be creating a struct, i.e. Person - passing in the snapshot and then dealing with the info within the snapshot. Do what the complier suggests to get it tot run. Force unwrap is ok if you know its not going to be nil.

Comment: Hm it still doesn't seem to the trick for me and I also tried the comment (snapshot.childSnapshotForPath("full_name").value as! String) and I get the error "Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSString'). I tried looking through the tutorial link too but I couldn't find specifically how to retrieve certain data :-(

Comment: sorry for all of these questions

Comment: No worries - bit by bit you'll understand more about firebase. Look at rays tutorials i posted before will help you out a lot.

Comment: What's the Swift 3 way of doing this? `snapshot.value["key"]` doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4**

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "user")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        if !snapshot.exists() { return }

        print(snapshot) // Its print all values including Snap (User)

        print(snapshot.value!)

        let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "full_name").value
        print(username!)

    })
```

Comment: Should look something like this in the current version
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
                            let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
                            ref.child("Users").child(userID ?? "").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in })

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "rules": {
         "tbl_name": {
            ".indexOn": ["field_name1", "field_name2"]
         },
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

You can apply indexOn on any field. Add this json in rules security and rules tab.
Hope this works for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

It retrieves logged in user data:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "DATABASE_URl")
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
let usersRef = ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
print(snapshot)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users/stephenwarren001@yahoo.com")


    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap : DataSnapshot)  in

        print("\(String(describing:  snap.value))")


    }) { (err: Error) in


        print("\(err.localizedDescription)")

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var refDatabase = DatabaseReference()

    refDatabase = Database.database().reference().child("users");
 let refUserIdChild = refDatabase.child("stephenwarren001@yahoo.com")
                    
                    refUserIdChild.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                        if !snapshot.exists() { return }

                        print(snapshot) // Its print all values including Snap (User)

                        print(snapshot.value!)
                        

                    if let tempDic : Dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>
                    {
                           
                            if let userName = tempDic["full_name"] as? String {
                                  self.tfName.text = userName

                              }

                            if let email = tempDic["email"] as? String {
                                    self.tfEmail.text  = email

                              }

                           
                    }


                    })
```