# Retrieving data from currently logged in user Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried many solutions to make this work, but it doesn't seem to work with me. These are the solutions I have tried:

[Firebase Retrieving Data in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759614/firebase-retrieving-data-in-swift)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

https://www.raywenderlich.com/187417/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-3

[image: My database]

I am trying to retrieve the deviceToken of the currently logged in user, for example if John logs in, it would assign or retrieve his deviceToken and assign it to a variable.

The closest I have got was with this code, but I get every profile with every data stored in that profile instead of the currently logged in one.

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users/profile/\(userID)")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if !snapshot.exists() { 
        return 
    }       

    let token = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "deviceToken").value
    print(token!)

})
```

Comment: Since you're getting data for the node one level above of what's desired, are you sure the user is logged in and a uid exists? What do you see when you print the userID? Alternatively, what happens if you try let ref = Database.database().refrerence(withPath: "users/profile").child(userId)?

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on the documentation, modifying for your case:

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("users").child("profile").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
// Get user value
let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
let deviceToken = value?["deviceToken"] as? Int ?? ""

// ...
}) { (error) in
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: I get an error that says "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" for the let user = User(deviceToken: deviceToken) part.

Comment: Turns out I can just comment it out and ignore that line. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in your case it is not needed. I have deleted that line.