# Observer not calling in swift iOS firebase realtime database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app which uses firebase realtime database. Here is my database content.

[image: Database content]

Here when ever a new child node is added to Request node I need to fetch the Phno and Message value and print it in the console.
Here is my observer code

```
user.observe(.childAdded) { (DataSnapshot) in
       print("Inside")
       if let dict = DataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary
       {
        for i in dict.allKeys
        {
            if let data = dict[i] as? NSDictionary
            {
                let message = data["Message"] as! String
                let phno = data["Phno"] as! String
                
                if(message != "" && phno != "")
                {
                    print(message)
                    print(phno)
                }
            
        }
       }
        
    }
```

I placed above code inside a function and called it in viewdidload() for first time. After which I tried manually adding child node to request node but the observer is not triggering.And I used that "inside" print statement for debugging and I found something strange in log output

[image: Log output]

As you can see the Inside is called once during view did load but again it is called without even making any changes to the data. How can I solve this problem so that trigger get called when ever a new child node is added to request node

Comment: .childAdded events are called once for each node and then when child nodes are added thereafter. It looks like you've added that to the *bill* node, so it's called for two child nodes; the *Request* node and then the *name* node. The request node has child data which matches the output you're showing. See the getting started guide [Listen for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events). What are you attempting to do? Can you clarify the question? Oh, please add code and structures as text so we can copy/paste them into answers when needed.

Comment: I'm building an app similar to social media all the data about bill willl be displayed in another app as a post along with comment option.When another app user adds a comment(with their phone no and message)the comments will be added a child to request node and I need to retrieve the all child nodes of the request node and display it in my app. I need to retrieve the c children node of request node whenever a new child is added to it

Comment: @RetroModernGamer just put that observe code in viewwillappear method.

Comment: @RB's Not sure what your comment means in relation to the question but moving it won't affect the issue.

Comment: @Jay i am taking about continues observe data from firebase retro  need to called that data every time i suggested him to put that observe code to `willappear` method so every time it will call and get that data.

Comment: @RB's You don't need to do that. Once an observer is attached to a node it will continue to receive events; it could be called in viewDid of viewWill or when the user clicked a button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is asking how to get to the child node data contained within the Request parent node. If so, try this:

First, we want somewhere to store that data so I've created a class to hold each request and then an array to hold all of the requests

```
class RequestClass {
    var key = ""
    var msg = ""
    var phone = ""

    convenience init(withSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.key = withSnapshot.key
        self.msg = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Message").value as? String ?? "no msg"
        self.phone = withSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Phno").value as? String ?? "no phone"
    }
}

var requestArray = [RequestClass]()
```

Then we add an observer to the Request node. A .childAdded observer will initially iterate over each child and then present any newly added children thereafter which in turn will add it to the array. `self.ref` is a class var that points to my firebase root.

```
func readRequests() {
    let requestRef = self.ref.child("bill").child("Request")
    requestRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        let request = RequestClass(withSnapshot: snapshot)
        self.requestArray.append(request)
    })
}
```

The above will read the node in the question and store each request in the array. Afterwards, to test, we can print those out

```
self.requestArray.forEach { print($0.key, $0.msg, $0.phone)}
```

and the output is

```
EEC8A no message no phone
REQ2 Hello 2353476346346
REQ3 K 12312
```